# Very weird rruleset behavior

Tags: python, python-dateutil, rrule

Using the latest dateutil available on pip, I'm getting strange time and ordering-dependent behavior when calling the `count` method using a recurring `DAILY` rrule.

```
>>> import dateutil
>>> dateutil.__version__
'2.4.2'
>>> from dateutil import rrule
>>> import datetime

>>> rules = rrule.rruleset()
>>> rules.rrule(rrule.rrule(rrule.DAILY, until=datetime.datetime(2038,1,1,0,0,0)))
>>> rules.count()
8179
>>> rules.exrule(rrule.rrule(rrule.DAILY, until=datetime.datetime(2038,1,1,0,0,0)))
>>> rules.count()
8179  # ??? Expected 0

>>> rules = rrule.rruleset()
>>> rules.exrule(rrule.rrule(rrule.DAILY, until=datetime.datetime(2038,1,1,0,0,0)))
>>> rules.rrule(rrule.rrule(rrule.DAILY, until=datetime.datetime(2038,1,1,0,0,0)))
>>> rules.count()
8179  # ??? Expected 0

>>> rules = rrule.rruleset()
>>> rules.exrule(rrule.rrule(rrule.DAILY, until=datetime.datetime(2038,1,1,0,0,0)))
>>> rules.count()
0
>>> rules.rrule(rrule.rrule(rrule.DAILY, until=datetime.datetime(2038,1,1,0,0,0)))
>>> rules.count()
0  # Now its working???

>>> rules = rrule.rruleset()
>>> rules.exrule(rrule.rrule(rrule.DAILY, until=datetime.datetime(2038,1,1,0,0,0)))
>>> rules.rrule(rrule.rrule(rrule.DAILY, until=datetime.datetime(2038,1,1,0,0,0)))
>>> rules.count()
8179  # ??? Expected 0

>>> rules = rrule.rruleset()
>>> rules.count()
0
>>> rules.rrule(rrule.rrule(rrule.DAILY, until=datetime.datetime(2038,1,1,0,0,0)))
>>> rules.count()
0  # WHAT???
>>> rules.count()
0

>>> rules = rrule.rruleset()
>>> rules.rrule(rrule.rrule(rrule.DAILY, until=datetime.datetime(2038,1,1,0,0,0)))
>>> rules.count()
8179  # IM DONE... WTF
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is simple, its because you have not included the `dtstart` parameter when creating the ruleset, when that is not included it defaults to `datetime.datetime.now()` , which is the current time, and it contains components upto the current microsecond.

Hence, when you first create the ruleset using -

```
>>> rules = rrule.rruleset()
>>> rules.rrule(rrule.rrule(rrule.DAILY, until=datetime.datetime(2038,1,1,0,0,0)))
>>> rules.count()
8179
```

You got entries by starting at the current time , upto microsecond.

After some time, when you again try -

```
rules.exrule(rrule.rrule(rrule.DAILY, until=datetime.datetime(2038,1,1,0,0,0)))
```

You are again creating a `rrule.rrule` object, by starting at current time , so its not the same as the previous one that you have created in `rules`.

To fix the issue, you can specify the `dtstart` attribute to make sure it starts at the same time.

Example -

```
>>> rules = rrule.rruleset()
>>> rules.rrule(rrule.rrule(rrule.DAILY, until=datetime.datetime(2038,1,1,0,0,0), dtstart=datetime.datetime(now.year,now.month,now.day,0,0,0)))
>>> rules.count()
8179
>>> rules.exrule(rrule.rrule(rrule.DAILY, until=datetime.datetime(2038,1,1,0,0,0), dtstart=datetime.datetime(now.year,now.month,now.day,0,0,0)))
>>> l3 = list(rules)
>>> len(l3)
0
>>> rules.count()
0
```

Similar issue occurs throughout your other examples.

---

Given the above, I think there is an issue in the dateutil code, where they are actually caching the count (length) of ruleset when you first time call `count()` , and then its correct length is only recalculated when you iterate over it, etc.

The issue occurs in `rrulebase` class, which is the base class for `ruleset` . The code from that is (source - https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil/blob/master/dateutil/rrule.py) -

```
def count(self):
    """ Returns the number of recurrences in this set. It will have go
        trough the whole recurrence, if this hasn't been done before. """
    if self._len is None:
        for x in self:
            pass
    return self._len
```

So, even after applying `exrule()` if you had previously called `.count()`, it would keep giving back the same count.

I am not 100% sure if its a bug or if its intended to behave like that , most probably it is a bug.

I have openned [issue](https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil/issues/104) for this.

Comment: Awesome. So the exrule didn't apply because it applies to a time microseconds after I made the original rrule. Thanks so much!

Comment: Just FYI , if you want to know , I openned issue - https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil/issues/104 - for the second one I said.